# Dynamically change style of a site running in EXPRESS js and NODE js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have a basic site running with node.js and express.js. I followed this [tutorial](http://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/) to get it done.

Express implementations looks like this. I have jade file for a web interface.

```js
// app.js
var express = require('express'),
  routes = require('./routes'),
  user = require('./routes/user'),
  http = require('http'),
  path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Home'
  });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

```html
# index.jade
html
  head
    title iDesk
    style.
      .available{
      background: #3db72f;
      }
      .occupied{
      background: red;
      }
  body
    table(width='40%')
      caption Table #01
      tr
        td#sec_01.available
    br
```

I also have another javascript that fetches a value from bluetooth. It has an infinite while loop and should be continuously run in node.js. And with the values it fetches, I want to dynamically change the style of the web interface. For example, when the value fetched from bluetooth is `1`, I want to change class style. ie. `document.getElementById("set_01").className = "occupied";`

How can I possibly combine these two features? Should they run seperately and find some way to transfer data to each other? Or can bluetooth.js be included in express.js and run in node altogether? I am new to both express and node js... Your help would be greatly appreciated... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have an javascript which communicates with bluetooth, the way to transfer any information dynamically to web-client is to use webscockets in client.

Loot at [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Comment: Is perfectly suits my purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a server side technology. When your client (for example a browser) makes a request to your node server, it processes the request entirely, sends you the result, and then is done communicating with your client (unless your client opens a new connection). When your server updates, usually there is no way to push something to the client (as that would be a massive security hole). Instead, your client must attempt to pull the new data. This is usually done via an AJAX call in the client-side javascript.

I don't have the full context of what you are trying to do here, but from what I can tell, you want to include bluetooth.js in the node.js files, but you also want to add a client side javascript file that will produce an ajax call to the bluetooth.js file at some event (possibly some time or a button press) and then based on the result of that call, update the html on the website. Presumably bluetooth.js needs access to hardware attached to the server, so you cannot directly load that to the client.

Hope this answers your question :)